# Dumping a huge List in Intellij-Idea while debugging

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way in Idea to dump the content of a large List of doubles into the clipboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click variable
2. Evaluate expression
3. Type *arrayName*.toString()
4. Click evaluate

[image]

Comment: You could also create a custom data type renderer: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugger-data-type-renderers.html.