How do I see full contents of array in IntelliJ Debugger?
How do I see full contents of a Java array in IntelliJ Debugger? Here's what I get for a relatively large byte array. So far, I couldn't find a way to expand the trimmed value
package org.example._misc;


import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class GenericTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            sb.append(getRandomCharacter());
        }
        String s = sb.toString();
        byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(); // dummy statement to stop the debugger and evaluate bytes
    }

    private char getRandomCharacter() {
        return (char)(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(26) + 'a');
    }
}

[106, 110, 113, 119, 97, 117, 107, 102, 104, 118, 121, 104, 118, 122, 109, 
112, 121, 119, 119, 107, 111, 97, 113, 119, 107, 106, 115, 114, 122, 118, 
101, 122, 118, 101, 106, 109, 113, 121, 97, 101, 97, 97, 110, 107, 106, 
107, 106, 98, 117, 103, 99, 98, 110, 110, 106, 113, 106, 110, 100, 100, 
120, 112, 115, 103, 105, 101, 115, 100, 100, 122, 102, 110, 118, 121, 116, 
97, 120, 106, 115, 119, 101, 120, 98, 111, 109, 97, 119, 121, 116, 116, 
109, 107, 97, 97, 98, 119, 106, 121, 100, 99, +900 more]


This SO answer, while useful, requires defining a custom renderer for every array type which is troublesome

I highlighted your question, right-clicked, and selected "Search Google". It said to hit <Alt>+<F8>. What happened when you did this? Did you see https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2023/04/debugger-upskill-variables-evaluate-expression-watches/ ? Do either of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549721/dumping-a-huge-array-in-intellij-idea-debugger or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163406/dumping-a-huge-list-in-intellij-idea-while-debugging

@rand'Chris I addressed the first of the two suggested SO questions in my latest edition. The other one is not really applicable since you can't get a meaningful string representation by calling toString() on a Java array (Arrays.toString, on the other hand, is more useful)

@rand'Chris Alt + F8 is simply a shortcut for Evaluate Expression. The blog page doesn't address the issue at hand at all

Thanks for updating your question. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with this tool. Your screenshot shows an "Evaluate expression..." prompt. As a C programmer, I'd enter "bytes + 100" to get an offset. It may be a bit tedious, but if you can't do that can you call some sort of .slice() method in there? I also don't understand why you can't use Arrays.toString(). Are you saying that it clips the string at the same place?
